# Animations of MenuFlyout in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

How to change the animations of MenuFlyout in Windows phone 8.1. Whenever the menuflyout is opened, the content in the background zooms out and get darker. and when the menuflyout is disabled there is different animation. How to change these animations. I tried changing in generic.xaml file but it didnt work. Thanks in Advance.